# How to switch to a Frame in main

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to go back to the main page when user presses on the `Done` button.

I have two files:

`gui_main.py`: the main gui that has several Frames

`gui_scan.py`: performs a scan and returns back to main menu Frame located in `gui_main.py` when user presses the `Done` button.

**Problem:** Whenever I called a frame from `gui_main.py`, I get a `KeyError` because the frame is not located in the frames list in main.
After alot of debugging, I found out I am referencing the frame in `gui_main.py` incorrectly. This is how I am referencing it:

Here is an MVCE equivalent code:

```
#gui_main.py
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk 

# External file imports
import gui_scan as scan
from gui_frame import PageFrame


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print("Loading")

        print ("Constructing Frames")
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne,Menu, Settings, scan.PerformScan):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame 

    def show_frame(self, frame_name):
        """ Show @frame_name frame """ 
        self.active_frame = self.frames[frame_name]  # <-- this causes the error
        self.active_frame.tkraise()

# PageOne Frame Class
class PageOne(PageFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    """ ...."""
    # Implementation of this is iirelavant to question

# Menu Frame Class  
class Menu(PageFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    """ ...."""
    # Implementation of this is iirelavant to question

# Settings Frame Class
class Settings(PageFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    """ ...."""
    # Implementation of this is iirelavant to question

if __name__ =="__main__":
    try:
        app = MainWindow()
    except Exception:
        # Problems
        print ("Problems running GUI")
```

The other file:

```
#gui_scan.py
import tkinter as tk 

from gui_frame import PageFrame
import gui_main as main 

class PerformScan(PageFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        PageFrame.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        label = tk.Label(self, padx=0, text="When you are ready press \"Start\" \n", justify=tk.CENTER)
        label.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=lambda: self.run_scan())
        button.pack()

    def run_scan(self):
        """ Run a scan"""
        # The scan runs here

        # at the end, have the user press `Done` and go back to Menu from `gui_main.py`
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self.final_frame, bg="red")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text = "Done",
            command = lambda:self.controller.show_frame(main.Menu)) # <-- this is wrong,(I think)
        self.button.grid(row = 0, column=3, padx = 5)
        self.button_frame.pack()
```

**Debugging:**
*Printing out frames in self.frames from main_gui:*

```
Frame:  <class '__main__.PageOne'>
Frame:  <class '__main__.Menu'>
Frame:  <class '__main__.Settings'>
Frame:  <class 'gui_scan.PerformScan'>
```

Pressing the `Done` button in `run_scan(self)` passes in this:

```
<class 'gui_main.Menu'>
```

This yields in an error, and I am stuck at whatever Frame I am at instead of switching back to the `Menu` frame.

Comment: Have you tried running your mcve? It doesn't. There's just too much broken to see a button to press (GUI won't start).

Comment: the module gui_frame.py is missing to help you, then check the import inside each file

Comment: @RonNorris I apologize for having a novice MCVE. I cannot include everything,because I did not write the code and I'm just continuing on the development.I do not have the copyright to the code, and I'm renaming everything in the MCVE that I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

**Solution:**

Separate `class PageOne(PageFrame)` , `class Menu(PageFrame)`, and `class Settings(PageFrame)` from the main file, and import them inside `gui_scan.py`.  This avoids the problem of trying to import the main file, and also makes the main file more organized.